# How to achive given Baseline to next Ascender distance by css

Tags: html, css

For example my `<p>` has a `font-size:20px` and a `line-height:50px`. `<h1>` and `<h2>` have some other values. I want the distance of the baseline from my `<p>` text to the top of the letter (Ascender) from the next element e.g. `h1` or `h2` to be say 35px. How can i achive that by css?

using margin gives me always the distance between the line-heights and not the letters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the `line-height, padding, margin` for all the elements. After that apply `padding-bottom:35px` to the element p,h1,h2.

```
 * {line-height:24px !important; padding:0; margin:0;}
 p,h1,h2{padding-bottom:35px;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/662abq50/1/)

Comment: but i want my text to have the line-height. for example when the p goes over 3 lines i want those three to have 50px line height. and when after that an < h > section comes, i want the top of the letters in its first line to be 35px bellow the baseline of the letters in the last < p > line.